# Why values [2][0] and [2][1] of glm::frustumLH_ZO are negated?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

Let's say I am coming from a left-handed world space. My positive Z is into the screen, and my Y is up, the same as OpenGL's default in clip space.

It is my understanding that, when coming from a right-handed world space (which is somewhat required when using older functions such as gluLookAt which maps the forward vector to the -Z axis) the Z co-ordinated is flipped before computing the projection matrix (orthographic/perspective). This is due to the fact that a right-handed system would have negative Z into the screen, which needs to be flipped before being passed to OpenGL.

I have confirmed that, for a function such as orthoLH_ZO, no flipping takes place. In fact, the matrix is a "standard" orthographic projection that also works in e.g. Vulkan i.e. it keeps the handedness (except for the fact that Y would be down in Vulkan so bottom and top would switch).

I would therefore expect glm::frustumLH_ZO to also be such a "standard" matrix since no flip needs to take place. However, when looking at its source code, elements [2][0] and [2][1] are negated compared to e.g. Vulkan's frustum perspective projection matrix (discussed [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0_ONQQ5ZNM&list=PL8327DO66nu9qYVKLDmdLW_84-yE4auCR&index=15) at 11:49).

These elements are:

```
Result[2][0] = (right + left) / (right - left);
Result[2][1] = (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
```

instead of my expected:

```
Result[2][0] = -(right + left) / (right - left);
Result[2][1] = -(top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
```

I don't believe this is due to a Z-flip, as that should also cause e.g. element [2][3] to be -1 and not +1.

Why are these entries in the matrix flipped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why are these entries in the matrix flipped?

You are right, they shouldn't be, [but they are in the most recent glm code base to date](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/06ed280db4e274fa5e1f36d5ea4f7dfd654ff9b0/glm/ext/matrix_clip_space.inl#L128-L129). Looks like you found a bug in glm. It did probably go unnoticed so long because a) most people use glm with default GL conventions, and b) these two elements are typically 0 in your standard symmetrical frustum (`left = -right` and `top = -bottom`).

Comment: I recommend creating a github issue for this.

Comment: Shoh, I thought I was going crazy. thanks for confirming this for me. I will make a PR tomorrow

Comment: Well look at that, it's already been reported. Obviously just needs a merge to master https://github.com/g-truc/glm/pull/1080/commits/5f95999f32006b1197403263b33beb7987bfa973